# How come there is "Integer Overflow and Underflow" in string variables in smart contracts?

Tags: string, solidity, smartcontracts, integer-overflow

I was analyzing a contract in [Oyente](https://github.com/enzymefinance/oyente#readme). The contract is :

```js
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Test{
    address admin;

    function Test() public{
        admin = msg.sender;
    }

    string str = "";

    function setStr(string _str) public{
        str = _str;
    }

    function getStr() public view returns (string){
        return str;
    }
}
```

When I passed this contract to oyente to analyze then the following report came:

```
INFO:root:contract Test.sol:Test:

INFO:symExec:   ============ Results ===========

INFO:symExec:     EVM Code Coverage:             24.1%

INFO:symExec:     Integer Underflow:             True

INFO:symExec:     Integer Overflow:              True

INFO:symExec:     Parity Multisig Bug 2:         False

INFO:symExec:     Callstack Depth Attack Vulnerability:  False

INFO:symExec:     Transaction-Ordering Dependence (TOD): False

INFO:symExec:     Timestamp Dependency:          False

INFO:symExec:     Re-Entrancy Vulnerability:         False

INFO:symExec:Test.sol:16:9: Warning: Integer Underflow.

        return str

Integer Underflow occurs if:

    return str = 1

INFO:symExec:Test.sol:11:5: Warning: Integer Overflow.

    function setStr(string _str) public{

    ^

Spanning multiple lines.

Integer Overflow occurs if:

    _str = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639932

INFO:symExec:   ====== Analysis Completed ======
```

It shows Integer overflow and underflow in a string variable. I really don't understand how it could happen or how to solve it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's a false positive result.

Value of the `string` type is stored as a byte array, not as an integer. If you convert the specified integers into byte array, and then try to return them as `string`, the value is not readable.

Example:

```
function getStr2() public view returns (string) {
    bytes memory byteArray = abi.encode(115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639932);
    return string(byteArray);
}
```

Fails in Remix IDE (uses [JS VM emulator](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/vm) and [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/)) with error:

> *Failed to decode output: null: invalid codepoint at offset 0; bad codepoint prefix (argument="bytes", value=Uint8Array(0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffc), code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=strings/5.5.0)*

Which [signalizes](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/strings/src.ts/utf8.ts#L26) that the "string" contains some UTF-8 bytes but doesn't start with the UTF-8 BOM.

---

Same goes for the value `1`.

Solidity strings span across multiple slots (each slot has 32 bytes), where the first slot contains the string length.

So if they set the `str` value to `0x01`, this suggests the array should have a length of 1. And then - depending on their emulator and the tool implementation, it:

- Either throws a [panic error](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/control-structures.html#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require) trying to access unallocated memory. They might interpret it as integer underflow, as it also causes a panic error.
- Or returns the default slot value `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (32 empty bytes), which is still not the expected value `0x01`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. I would very much like to know if there is any way to get past this and get "False" instead of "True" for Integer overflow and underflow. Thanks again.

Comment: @MHS I'm not familiar with this specific tool, nor skilled in Python (in which is it written). It seems that [this line](https://github.com/enzymefinance/oyente/blob/master/oyente/symExec.py#L818) adds the error to the array of int overflow occurrences (effectively showing `true` in the result if the array is not empty). Ln 787 checks if the `ADD` EVM opcode was used. But this specific opcode is also used when you're resizing a Solidity array (string is a representation of a byte array) - not just with arithmetics. So the tool might just use incorrect logic from the start, I'm not really sure.